# Write a function which draws boxes on the screen in matlab

Tags: matlab

The function is called with a character  (ch) as the first argument and two positive integers which represent the width and the height of the box to be drawn. It automatically draws a box with the character (ch) by the specified width and height.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owpk9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read this on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi check now i have added a picture with it

Comment: @HamidKhan You misunderstand. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. If you have code that you need help with, you'll probably get help. If you try to assign us homework, you probably won't.

Comment: Check this: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/314681-write-a-function-drawbox-which-draws-boxes-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
function drawBox(str,w,h)
ch = [0. 0.] ;
%% get four corners of box
N = 20 ;
x = linspace(ch(1),ch(1)+w,N) ;
y = linspace(ch(2),ch(2)+h,N) ;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) ;
X(2:end-1,2:end-1) = NaN ;
Y(2:end-1,2:end-1) = NaN ;
x = X(~isnan(X)) ;y = Y(~isnan(Y)) ;
plot(x,y,'.w') ; hold on
text(x,y,str)
axis off
```

Source: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/314681-write-a-function-drawbox-which-draws-boxes-on-the-screen